# Doxygen and "self" keyword on PHP documentation

Tags: php, doxygen

I'm tryin to document a my PHP library with doxygen, but I cannot configure it to let recognize the correct usage of member function  of my class, using the keyword "self". For instance the following code:

```
Class myclass{
    public static function myfunc1(){
      return 10; }
    public static function myfunc2(){
      return self::myfunc1(); }
}
```

is not correctly documented. Doxygen maps the two funcions, but when it refer to the internal or external call to these function, it doesn't take in account the myfunc1 called by myfunc2.

My workaround at the moment is to changed the code as follows:

```
Class myclass{
    public static function myfunc1(){
      return 10; }
    public static function myfunc2(){
      return myclass::myfunc1(); }
}
```

In this case doxygen refers correctly to the usage of myfunc1 related to myfunc2. Of course I don't like very much this solution. How can I solve this issue?
thank you very much

Comment: can you share the part of the documentation you've been reading?

Comment: Please also state the version of doxygen.

Comment: I'm using doxygen version 1.8.3.1 under windows

Comment: Technically, `myclass::myfunc1();` is more correct than `self::myfunc1();`, as `self` can resolve to a `myclass` *object*, while `myclass::` is explicitly static.

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch on github to recognize the self keyword, pull request #6430 (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6430)

Answer (score 3):

Doxygen provides input filter option, which enables us to change the source code at the time of documentation creation. For e.g. It gives us ability to intercept the code and change the code `self::myfunc1` to `myclass::myfunc1` on fly, which Doxygen understands. It does not change the actual source code in any way.

I have created a filter based on code from [Doxygen PHP Filters](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters) with some modifications, which can do the changes for you.

Please create a file /path/to/selfFilter.php and put the code inside it:

```
<?php
//Create file /path/to/selfFilter.php

$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
$classes = array();
foreach($tokens as $key => $token)
{
    if($token[0] == T_CLASS)
        $classes[] = $tokens[$key+2][1];
}
if(!empty($classes))
{
    list($source, $tail) = explode('class ' . $classes[0], $source, 2);
    $class_code = '';
    for($i = 1; $i < count($classes); $i++)
    {
        list($class_code, $tail) = explode('class ' . $classes[$i], $tail, 2);
        $class_code = preg_replace('#\bself::#', $classes[$i-1].'::', $class_code);
        $source .= 'class ' . $classes[$i-1] . $class_code;
    }
    $class_code = preg_replace('#\bself::#', $classes[count($classes)-1].'::', $tail);
    $source .= 'class ' . $classes[count($classes)-1] . $class_code;

}

echo $source;
```

Update the following options in your doxygen config file.

```
INPUT_FILTER           = "php /path/to/selfFilter.php"
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = YES
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
```

Please make sure that the `/path/to/selfFilter.php` is executable and php is available on the path, otherwise use the full php path

```
INPUT_FILTER           = /usr/bin/php /path/to/selfFilter.php
```

If you run the Doxygen now it should work. Please let me know if you have any issues.

*Note: The keyword 'class' should be defined in lower case for the above filters to work.*

Comment: It sounds a good solution but I'm under windows with doxygen 1.8.3.1 and the statement php as input_filter is unknown. Probably should I have php installed on the same machine running doxygen?

Comment: that is awesome!

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! It looks like it only picks up the first class defined in the file, but since there's only one class per file it works out fine for me.

Comment: @st3fano68 As this feature is not natively available to Doxygen, you should have PHP installed on the machine you are running the Doxygen from. You can also change the PHP filter script to any other language which might be available on your machine. e.g. Python, C++

Comment: @LarryB. Thanks for your suggestion, I have updated the code so it should work for a file which might have multiple class definitions within it.

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch on github to recognize the self keyword, pull request #6430 (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6430)